# retrofit inside android library

Tags: android, retrofit, mvp, android-library

I wonder if anyone have some knowledge about using retrofit in android, as a library module.

I ask it, after searching a lot on internet, becuase of the many exercises related to MVP and android development using clean architecture, spliting the app in modules.

Best regards.

Comment: Using Retrofit in a library module should be no different than using Retrofit in an app module.

Comment: What is the issue? Using retrofit in a library is fine.

Comment: Im trying to compile a java project (maven module, eclipse ide) for using an http client from within it. but gets me an exception with this name: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Comment: I needed to add the retrofit library in the main app using gradle to make it work, but not sure whether this is the optimized solution.